# How to configure "cloning repository" in Eclipse's Git

Tags: eclipse, git

In Eclipse, should the *cloning repository* point to my Java project root, which is cloned through `git clone ...`, or it seems by default it points to `C:\users\john\git`.

Should I change the default cloning repository, or should I leave it as is? I thought it should point to the root directory of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't perform *Import...* → *Git* → *Projects from Git* → *Clone URI* in a project context, so it takes `<USER HOME>/git` as natural choice. I'd change it to your project's or an according sub-directory like `src`, `code` or the like.